# php filectime returns an error

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to make a site in which to display all the digital movies I own. I am currently working on a page to scan the movies directory and read each movie in there and extract the name and insert it into my mysql database.

I also need to pull the creation date from the file and insert that as well. Yet when i searched here on OS i tried all the examples i could find and i get errors with all of them and cannot figure out where the error is coming from. I also need to format the creation date a certain way so it fits the format in the MySQL database.

I am working on a windows based machine.

**Code:**

```
include("config.php");

echo '<ul>';
if ($handle = opendir('M:/Movies/')) {

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != '$RECYCLE.BIN' && $entry != 'System Volume Information' && $entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
    $replace = array(".avi",".mkv",".mp4");
    $title = str_replace($replace, "", $entry);
    $exists = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `mdw_movies` WHERE `title` LIKE "'.$title.'%"');
    $exists1 = mysql_num_rows($exists);
        if ($exists1 == 0) {
            $date = date('Y-m-d', filectime($entry)); // This is line 15
            $query = "INSERT INTO `mdw_movies` (`title`) VALUES ('".$title."')";
            mysql_query($query);
            print "<li>Inserted Movie <b>".$title."</b> (<b>".$date."</b>).</li>";
        }
    }
}
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**Error:**

```
Warning: filectime(): stat failed for Assassin's Creed - Embers.mp4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\movies\read.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after awhile of reading through the php manual on filectime. I was missing a directory listing for the file in the filectime() function.

Here is my correct code for people to reference:

```
include("config.php");

$dir = 'M:/Movies/';

echo '<ol>';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != '$RECYCLE.BIN' && $entry != 'System Volume Information' && $entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
    $replace = array(".avi",".mkv",".mp4");
    $title = str_replace($replace, "", $entry);
    $exists = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `mdw_movies` WHERE `title` LIKE "'.$title.'%"');
    $exists1 = mysql_num_rows($exists);
        if ($exists1 == 0) {
            $date = date('Y-m-d', filectime($dir.$entry));
            $query = "INSERT INTO `mdw_movies` (`title`,`posted`) VALUES ('".$title."','".$date."')";
            mysql_query($query);
            print "<li>Inserted Movie <b>".$title."</b> (<b>".$date."</b>).</li>";
        }
    }
}
}
echo '</ol>';
```